# Python Generic typehint going from type to instanciated object

Tags: python, type-hinting, metaclass

I currently am having some issues with my IDE autocomplete as it can't tell what return types are etc.

I have a singleton metaclass, overriding the `__call__` method similar to this:

```
SingletonTypes = typing.TypeVar("SingletonTypes")


class Singleton(ABCMeta):
    def __call__(cls: SingletonTypes, environment: str = None, *args, **kwargs) -> SingletonTypes:
        /* code here, will return an instanciated copy of cls */
        return super(Singleton, cls).__call__()
```

My issue is if I have the Generic typehint, and obviously cls is a type, and it returns the object. I'm not sure how to specify the typehints as such to indicate that, without python then getting confused.

If i try add `type(SingletonTypes)` to the cls typehint then it doesn't suggest anything as there is no consistency between SingletonType. Not really sure how to progress and would be nice to have functioning autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
def __call__(cls: Singleton, environment: str = None, *args, **kwargs) -> SingletonTypes:
```

Technically, this is what would be correct: cls is an instance of "Singleton" the metaclass for your singleton classes. But I am not sure how aware the tooling around annotations will be of the workings of metaclasses - in some aspects the tooling for type-hinting and annotations feels quite disjoint from the actual workings  of the language.

If that does not work, you should settle for using singletons without resorting to metaclasses, as that is overkill anyway.  Unless you need to have an `__init__` method that will run just once, and can't be in `__new__` , you just have to add the same logic you put in the metaclass' `__call__` to `__new__` on the class, or on a base class itself. Since thhis mechanism would use plain simple inheritance, the type-hinting machinnery should just work, with no special annotations needed:

```
class SingletonBase:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kw):
         if "_instance" in cls.__dict__:
             return cls._instance  # NB: this will still trigger a call to __init__ in subclasses
         instance = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kw)
         cls._instance= instance
         return instance
```

(I think maybe the type hinting mechanism can even find its way with no explicit annotations in this case, as the role of `__new__` is well defined in the language semantics)

Comment: I've just tried it now and doesn't work again. I think the issue is SingletonTypes is a generic, and python has no information on the actual output since it usually comes from a generic parameter.